# Why do I get this AmbiguousMatchException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am writing a simple .NET 7 web application that will respond to any GET request by serving the same Razor page. This is my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");
app.Run();
```

A request to https://localhost:7024/ returns my Razor page as expected. However, a request to https://localhost:7024/anythingelse throws an exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> /Index
> /Index
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[]
> candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.SelectAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateSet candidateSet)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet
> candidateSet)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware
> middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

Comment: You may have the same IP assigned to two different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial answer did not address your question: "Why do I get this...?" It just provided how to resolve the AmbiguousMatchException error. Here's an explanation of why this error occurs, along with a code sample that shows what's happening.

ASP.NET Core is creating multiple routes for `/Index`: 1. for the Razor Page with the file name `Index.cshtml`; and 2. for the root URL of the web app (or `https://localhost:7024/` in your question).

[image]

Navigating to `https://localhost:7024/` or `https://localhost:7024/index` works because these two route patterns have a clear match.

When `app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");` is set in `program.cs`, with the [first parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.razorpagesendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapfallbacktopage?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-razorpagesendpointroutebuilderextensions-mapfallbacktopage(microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-iendpointroutebuilder-system-string)) set to the page name: `/Index`, the request is routed to the page endpoint `/Index`. The ambiguous exception occurs because there are two routes that match the endpoint for `/Index`.

### Add a catch-all route template

Adding a catch-all route template (i.e. starting a route template with an asterik `*` followed by any word) as @Mike added in his answer, removes ambiguity.

```
@page "{*anyword}"
```

The catch-all route pattern, the second list item in the image below, matches `https://localhost:7024/anythingelse`.

Using a catch-all route pattern, however, in the `@page` directive in the `Index.cshtml` file in the root folder makes `app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");` redundant. All request paths will be processed by the catch-all route pattern.

[image]

### Add "/Index" template

Add "/Index" to the `@page` directive in the main index page also removes ambiguity. Only one endpoint to `/Index` is registered.

```
@page "/Index"
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

[image]

### EndpointDataList code sample

The following code sample was used generate the image results above. Replace the first line in `Index.cshtml`, that is, the `@page` directive with any of the following to get the output of the images above, in order:

```
@page
@page "{*anyword}"
@page "/Index"
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page "/Index"
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Display Name</th>
            <th>Route Pattern</th>
            <th>Url</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (EndpointData endpointData in @Model.EndpointDataList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@endpointData.DisplayName</td>
                <td>@endpointData.RoutePattern</td>
                <td>@endpointData.URL</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> _endpointSources;
        public IndexModel(
            IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointDataSources)
        {
            _endpointSources = endpointDataSources;
        }

        public IEnumerable<RouteEndpoint> EndpointSources { get; set; }
        public List<EndpointData> EndpointDataList { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            EndpointSources = _endpointSources
                        .SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints)
                        .OfType<RouteEndpoint>();

            EndpointDataList = new List<EndpointData>();

            foreach (RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint in EndpointSources)
            {
                // If the route pattern is an empty string then
                // it represents the home page. The home page is
                // represented by the route pattern '/Index'.

                EndpointData pageData = new()
                {
                    DisplayName = routeEndpoint.DisplayName,
                    RoutePattern = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.RawText,
                    URL = routeEndpoint.ToString()
                };
                EndpointDataList.Add(pageData);
            }
        }
    }

    public class EndpointData
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string RoutePattern { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/Index");
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware that will redirect all requests:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var wipPath = "/Home/WorkInProgress";
    if ((string)context.Request.Path != wipPath)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(wipPath);
        return;
    }
    await next();
});
```

Source: https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-redirect-requests-single-url-route/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single page to process all requests, add a "catchall" route template to it:

```
@page "{*catchall}"
```

You can inspect `Request.Path` for the actual URL, or you can add a public property named `CatchAll` with a `BindProperty` attribute with `SupportsGet = true` if you prefer to use model binding:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public string CatchAll { get; set; }
```